# IOPub data rate exceeded in Jupyter notebook and cannot be adjusted

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I got the following error after using trackpy.link in jupyter notebook:

IOPub message rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_msg_rate_limit`.

```
Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_msg_rate_limit=1000.0 (msgs/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)
```

I saw that many people suggested opening jupyter notebook as follows:
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000000

However I still get the exact same error, and it still says that the current value is 1000.0 (msgs/sec). What can I do differently?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem - for some reason whenever the laptop was being charged the code would stop working. As soon as I unplugged it, the code started working again. Weirdest bug ever.